# Side Menu Wont Scroll On Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have a side menu on my website. It works fine on PC but its not scrolling on mobile. I tried it on my iPhone 5 and iPad but no good. Also the toggle button is not working on internet explorer. I am stuck with this issue for a week right now and its getting frusturating.

URL is: www.koddersleri.com, website is in my native language.

JSBin:https://jsbin.com/zeqolacoke/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I took this sidebar from: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu and made some modifications.
I appreciate all the help.

Edit: I actually noticed that you have to touch the menu couple times on mobile than it starts working. But thats still not good.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `overflow-y: scroll;` to a different element in your css.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .side-menu-container > .navbar-nav {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```